# wp multisite: add new super admin

Tags: wordpress

How to create new super admin with wp multisite?

I have phpmyadmin access, admin wp-admin access, ftp access.

I'm unable to find wp_users info from the database nor I'm not able to find user id from wp-admin to grant_super_admin(x); with functions.php

Any idea how to crack this?

Comment: Edit user from wp-admin then take a look at the url. User ID is in the url user-edit.php?user_id=X

Comment: @RantoRasolomahefa Thanks I tried it already. It only shows wp-admin/profile.php and I tried all numbers manually in the url from 1-100 without any luck accessing my profile